# D3 Force-Directed Graph with Numerous Functionalities

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, d3.js

I have a d3.js force directed graph that is driven by the code below. I am relatively new to d3, and much of the code is pieced together from various examples found online. If anyone has a moment or two (even if only to review a portion of the code), I would greatly appreciate any help. The graph functions properly, but I imagine there are inefficiencies and "bad" code.

Some of my concerns:

1. Proper appending/creation of "svg" and "g"
2. Simplification of `zoom` functionality, and removal of zoom on double-click (not sure where to place `.on("dblclick.zoom", null)`
3. Proper implementation of `on change` functions like the dropdown driving the visualization at the top. Doesn't seem like the current implementation would easily allow for multiple dropdowns
4. Proper mixing of d3 `style`/`attr` and external CSS - currently seems quite haphazard
5. Overall inefficiencies and code mistakes (i.e. proper placement of functions, variables, etc.)

In addition to the snippet below, a working bl.ock is here: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/cf8482c5da0e5964abe44f493be9704a

JSON data in `test.json`:

```
{"nodes": [{"id": "Michael Scott", "type": "boss"}
          ,{"id": "Jim Halpert", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Pam Beasley", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Kevin Malone", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Angela", "type": "employee"}
          ,{"id": "Dwight Schrute", "type": "employee"}]
,"links": [{"source": "Michael Scott", "target": "Jim Halpert", "linkCount": 1, "type": "pro"}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "linkCount": 2, "type": "friend"}
          ,{"source": "Pam Beasley", "target": "Kevin Malone", "linkCount": 2, "type": "pro"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "linkCount": 3, "type": "friend"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "linkCount": 3, "type": "enemy"}
          ,{"source": "Angela", "target": "Dwight Schrute", "linkCount": 3, "type": "pro"}]
};
```

```js
var dropdown = d3.select("#selectLinkNumber")
    var change = function() {
    d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()
    var val = dropdown.node().options[dropdown.node().selectedIndex].value;

    d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
      if (error) throw error;

    var filteredLinks = graph.links.filter(d => d.linkCount >= val);

    var filteredNodes = Object.values(filteredLinks.reduce(function(t,v){
      if(!t[v.source]){
          t[v.source] = graph.nodes.filter(o => o.id === v.source)[0]
          }
      if(!t[v.target]){
          t[v.target] = graph.nodes.filter(o => o.id === v.target)[0]
          }
      return t;
      },{}))

    var filteredGraph = {
          nodes: filteredNodes,
          links: filteredLinks
      };

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width"),
      height = +svg.attr("height");

    var zoomHandler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomActions);

    zoomHandler(svg);

    var g = svg.append("g").call(zoomHandler); //Creates group for zoom

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("forceX", d3.forceX().strength(.4).x(width * .5))
      .force("forceY", d3.forceY().strength(.4).y(height * .5))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-25))
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    var tip = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .offset([-10, 0])
              .html(function(d) {
                  return "<div class=center>" + "<img src=" + d.image + " height=100 width=100>" + "</div>"
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "Name:" + "</span>" + d.name
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "ID:" + "</span>" + d.id
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "Type:" + "</span>" + d.type
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "Status:" + "</span>" + d.status
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "NodeAttribute1:" + "</span>" + d.NodeAttribute1
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "NodeAttribute2:" + "</span>" + d.NodeAttribute2
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "NodeAttribute3:" + "</span>" + d.NodeAttribute3
                  + "<br>" + "<span>" + "NodeAttribute4:" + "</span>" + d.NodeAttribute4
                });
    g.call(tip);

    var link = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(filteredGraph.links)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; })
      .style("fill", "none");

    var nodeColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
              .domain(["NodeType1", "NodeType2", "NodeType3", "NodeType4"])
              .range(["#005495", "#00C3FF", "#FF0000", "#FFC0CB"]);

    var node = g.append("g")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(filteredGraph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return nodeColor(d.statusType); })
        .attr("r", 2.5)
        .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstart)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragend))
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
      .on('click', connectedNodes)
      .on("dblclick", releasenode);

    simulation
      .nodes(filteredGraph.nodes)
      .on("tick", tick);

    simulation.force("link")
      .links(filteredGraph.links);

    var nodeLeg = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                  .domain(["NodeType1", "NodeType2", "NodeType3", "NodeType4"])
                  .range(["#005495", "#00C3FF", "#FF0000", "#FFC0CB"]);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodeLegendOrdinal")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20,15)");

    var nodeLegendOrdinal = d3.legendColor()
            .shape("path", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCircle).size(125)())
            .title("Employee Type")
            .scale(nodeLeg);

    svg.select(".nodeLegendOrdinal")
            .call(nodeLegendOrdinal);

    var linkLeg = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                  .domain(["LinkType1", "LinkType2", "LinkType3", "LinkType4"])
                  .range(["black", "#20a064", "#F45D01", "#005495"]);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "linkLegendOrdinal")
            .attr("transform", "translate(20,125)");

    var linkLegendOrdinal = d3.legendColor()
            .shape("rect")
            .shapeWidth(25)
            .shapeHeight(5)
            .title("Link Type")
            .scale(linkLeg);

    svg.select(".linkLegendOrdinal")
            .call(linkLegendOrdinal);

    var toggle = 0;

    var linkedByIndex = {};
      for (i = 0; i < filteredGraph.nodes.length; i++) {
          linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
            };
      filteredGraph.links.forEach(function (d) {
                linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
            });

    function neighboring(a, b) {
                return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
            }

    function connectedNodes() {

                if (toggle == 0) {
                    d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
                    node.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
                    });

                    link.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
                    });

                    toggle = 1;
                } else {
                    node.style("opacity", 1);
                    link.style("opacity", 1);
                    toggle = 0;
                }

            }

    filteredGraph.links.sort(function(a,b) {
      if (a.source > b.source) {return 1;}
      else if (a.source < b.source) {return -1;}
      else {
          if (a.target > b.target) {return 1;}
          if (a.target < b.target) {return -1;}
          else {return 0;}
      }
    });

    for (var i=0; i<filteredGraph.links.length; i++) {
      if (i != 0 &&
          filteredGraph.links[i].source == filteredGraph.links[i-1].source &&
          filteredGraph.links[i].target == filteredGraph.links[i-1].target) {
          filteredGraph.links[i].linknum = filteredGraph.links[i-1].linknum + 1;
          }
      else {filteredGraph.links[i].linknum = 1;};
    };

    function tick() {
    link.attr("d", linkArc);
    node.attr("transform", transform);
    }

    function linkArc(d) {
    var curve=2;
    var homogeneous=3.2;
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)*(d.linknum+homogeneous)/(curve*homogeneous);  //linknum is defined above
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }  

    function dragstart(d, i) {
      simulation.stop()
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragend(d, i) {
      simulation.alpha(0.3).restart();
    }

    function releasenode(d) {
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }

    function zoomActions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }

    })
    }
    dropdown.on("change", change)
    change();
```

```css
.links path {
  fill: none;
}

.link.pro {
  stroke: red;
}

.link.friend {
  stroke: #20a064;
}

.link.enemy {
  stroke: black;
}

nodes {
  fill: red;
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: "Ariel";
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align:center;
    font-style: underline;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Ariel";
}

h3 {
    color: black;
    text-align:center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Ariel";
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

span
{
    width:100px;
    clear:right;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right:2px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #00C3FF;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 175px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }

  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  #content {
      width:100%;
      max-width:800px;
      margin:0 auto;
      text-align:center;
      font-size: 20px;
  }

  .box {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 170px;
      width: 170px;
      margin:10px;
      overflow:auto;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #444;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css"/>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="d3-tip.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.24.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
    <title> Test </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
     <div class="center">
       <select id="selectLinkNumber" name="selectLinkNumber">
         <option value="1">Select Number of Links</option>
         <option value="2">Two or More Links</option>
         <option value="3">Three or More Links</option>
       </select>
     </div>
    </header>
    <svg width="900" height="600"></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added the outline of the required HTML and snippet, but the code doesn't run.  To give reviewers a clearer sense of how you're using the code, try changing the HTML to show a minimal working version.  Code like this is usually harder to review without that.

Comment: Thank you, Edward. Not well versed in how to manipulate the snippet, so I created a bl.ock instead. It includes everything that drives the visualization, along with some test data.

Comment: Thank you, again - and thank you for being understanding! I put the snippet back into the question, along with the CSS, HTML, and main JS. However, I'm not sure how to include the JSON so that the JS can call it. Or how to have the HTML call the JS for that matter.

Comment: I think it's close enough to help reviewers.  Hope you get some good reviews!

Comment: Thanks! I got it a little closer by at least including the JSON data inline.